# how to derive binary array from a list of strings

Tags: python, list, pandas, numpy

The problem is best described as an example (like most cases).

I have the following example list:

```
test = ['a','a','b','b','c','b']
```

I would like to get a list of pandas arrays with the length of the input list (6 in this case) where each array has length of the unique values in 'test' in that case 3 ('a', 'b' and 'c') and it contains zeroes and a single 1 corresponding to which value of the unique values (the order here obviously matters so it would be nice if the unique values are sorted or even better order would be as the values occur for the first time, in the example the two orders coincide) each element of the input list contains.

The output would be a list of arrays looking like this for the example above:

```
(1,0,0)
(1,0,0)
(0,1,0)
(0,1,0)
(0,0,1)
(0,1,0)
```

Additional example:

```
test = ['a', 'g', 'b']

(1,0,0)
(0,1,0)
(0,0,1)
```

I also need the order of the corresponding to the output unique values if arbitrary. It is best to be as the unique element is first encountered in the list. In this case it is 'a', 'g', 'b'.

Thank you

Comment: What happens if you have 'g' in that array? Is it possible? What would be the output for `test = ['a', 'g', 'b']` ?

Comment: `[tuple(int(t==c) for c in case) for t in test]` where `case = ('a', 'b', 'c')` and `test = ['a','a','b','b','c','b']`

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Look up "One-Hot Encoding"

Comment: @iBug, it should be a pandas array not a tuple

Comment: @criticalth what is a "pandas array"? Do you mean a `numpy.ndarray`? a `pandas.Series`??

Comment: Thers's nothing like **pandas array**. I think you got confused with **numpy.ndarray**

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga the comment is a valid point. Both numpy array or pandas series will do Akshay is also correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pandas has a built-in function, `get_dummies`, that might serve your purposes:

```
>>> test = ['a','a','b','b','c','b']
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.get_dummies(test)
   a  b  c
0  1  0  0
1  1  0  0
2  0  1  0
3  0  1  0
4  0  0  1
5  0  1  0
```

If for some reason, you really need a list of `numpy.ndarray` objects, you could always:

```
>>> list(pd.get_dummies(test).values)
[array([1, 0, 0], dtype=uint8), array([1, 0, 0], dtype=uint8), array([0, 1, 0], dtype=uint8), array([0, 1, 0], dtype=uint8), array([0, 0, 1], dtype=uint8), array([0, 1, 0], dtype=uint8)]
>>>
```

Comment: @criticalth by your last example, this solution, as neat as it is. doesn't work for you.

Comment: you are partly right. but I still get the order of the output in the column names in the data frame and I can easily rearrange that :) and the sort order was only a preference. I will accept this solution